# Menu - Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

He hecho un nuevo menu:
carpeta res > new Layout > menu.

En el he introducido 7 iconos.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/linterna"
        android:icon="@mipmap/linterna_montse"
        android:title="@string/linterna"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/camara"
        android:icon="@mipmap/camara_montse"
        android:title="@string/camara"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/animacio"
        android:icon="@mipmap/man_montse"
        android:title="@string/animacio"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/animacioTwen"
        android:icon="@mipmap/batman_montse"
        android:title="@string/animaciotwen"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/audio"
        android:icon="@mipmap/music_montse"
        android:title="@string/audio"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:icon="@mipmap/film_montse"
        android:title="@string/video"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/geolocalizacion"
        android:icon="@mipmap/near_montse"
        android:title="@string/geolocalizacion"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

El problema lo tengo que el 7 no cabe y el problema es que no se como hacer para que si quepa y quede todo centrado..

Podéis ayudarme?

Adjunto imagen de como queda con una pantalla grande, pero en el momento que la pantalla es mas pequeña los botones se cortan y no se muestran todos, como puedo hacer para que se hagan más pequeños según la pantalla? Es decir que salgan siempre los 7 botones.

[image: pantalla]

Comment: podrias agregar una imagen ?

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con que *el siete no cabe*?  ¿Que no cabe dónde?  Si pruebas a quitar temporalmente el seis si *cabe*  el siete?   ¿Será que usas una imagen más grande? Ponle temporalmente una imagen de la de los otros, o prueba a poner la imagen del siete también en el dos... Se debe hacer ese tipo de pruebas en estos casos para ver si son las dimensiones de la imagen o es otra cosa.

Comment: editado.. ya me diréis si ahora me explico mejor! :)

Comment: Para que se vean todos, dependerá en gran medida de la pantalla y de su resolución. En pantallas pequeñas lo más probable es que no se puedan mostrar todos por mucho que quieras. Revisa estas respuestas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558235/how-to-implement-a-menu-with-more-visible-items-in-android y https://stackoverflow.com/a/16772518/323149

Comment: Se me ha ocurrido hacer un scroll lateral en los botones, así si la ventana es más pequeña, no perderán tamaño. Si es esto lo que quieres, te lo puedo desarrollar.

Comment: necesito que sea encima, por eso decía si habia forma de hacer los iconos un poco más pequeños o de centrar. xD